# Laravel bootstrap is not working after install?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have started a new laravel project (my first). I have created some views and routs etc, but bootstrap is not working. I am using laravel 7.

I have followed these steps: https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel/how-to-install-bootstrap-in-laravel-6-7-by-example/ which seemed to work as it should

^which added bootstrap in the `package.json` file: but still it's not working.

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    }
```

have I done anything wrong? do I have to link it in some way or another?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to say when you dont post any javascript code. Check your browser dev tab for errors; 1001 things could have gone wrong.

Comment: I have only started a new laravel `laravel new example` created some pages `app.blade.php`,`home.blade.php` etc and followed the steps on the website. But when I try to add a bootstrap class to a div as an example it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you run:
npm run dev 
after npm install? The webpage only says the first command.

Did you put these script src and css links to the head of the html?(after compile)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had all the stylesheet links in a different place and forgot to @include them